# Are there any Object Databases for Ruby?

Tags: ruby, database, persistence, object-oriented-database

I cannot seem to find any Object Databases for Ruby (do not confuse with Document Oriented, like Coach and Mongo).

Do more or less mature OODBMSs for Ruby exist?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what the distinction is that you're making. What do you want to store, and how do you want to retrieve it?

Comment: Can you provide an example of an Object Database that you use outside of Ruby?

Comment: Sample [OODBs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_database) are siaqodb, db4o, stsdb. I want to store objects themselves.

Comment: Sorry, guys. It was a typo. I meant to say 'do not confuse with `Document` Oriented...'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know much about it, but I believe that the [MagLev](http://maglev.gemstone.com/) implementation of Ruby will include an object database.

Comment: MagLev looks very interesting. But any referenced object becomes persistent by default (which is too much I think). Still it looks like the most advanced OODB for Ruby so far.

Comment: If it is as good as GLASS, the Smalltalk/Seaside/Gemstone, you'll never enjoy looking at a rdbms again

Comment: Just to clarify a bit: it's not quite true that "any referenced object becomes persistent".  Only a reference from a persistent object will make an object persistent (at the next commit).  Many/most objects are transient and references from them will NOT cause an object to become persistent.

Comment: (@StephanEggermont Old thread, but yeah, Gemstone in a Smalltalk environment is a thing of beauty.)

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any mature ones — because it isn't typically done or desired by Rubyists.

Comment: It's not so much a case of "not welcomed" by rubyists.  I think there is just not that much call for it.  Many people are used to using ORMs rather than accessing OODBs directly in the vast majority of situations that Ruby is being used, and those (especially ActiveRecord) are very mature and well understood.

Comment: I think this answer is true by virtue of being practically tautological.  :-)  Because there are none, people who really want an OODB will either use Ruby for a while and leave it (like me), or look at it and decide not to pick it up.  If there is no real OODB solution today, then by definition today's Rubyists are those who don't strongly desire an OODB!

Comment: I guess I should add: all we really know is that the people who want an OODB and Ruby, apparently want to avoid writing (and maintaining) an OODB for Ruby more than they want both Ruby and an OODB together.  :-)

Comment: Well, MagLev is based on Gemstone, making it the most mature OODB.